# Robot Vacuum for Stairs?

Tags: smart-device

It's not clear whether this is in scope for this site or not, but after a recent back injury, I realized how nice it would be to have a robot that would vacuum my stairs (ideally floors too, but not necessarily).  Dyson recently filed a patent for a stair-cleaning robot (see https://gizmodo.com/yes-i-actually-do-want-a-creepy-dyson-robot-vacuum-tha-1847616552), but I haven't seen any for sale yet (at any price).  I'd love to know if any are available for under $1000?

Comment: I think this is on topic too, but I will have to ask Meta

Comment: Irsu85's corresponding Meta question: [Are questions about robot vacuum cleaners on-topic here?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/756/20202)